# Polymer Neon-Animation: How to use cascaded-animation and hero-animation together?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I have a small application that uses a `cascaded-animation` **AND** a `hero-animation` together [here](http://loveandhappiness.github.io/cascaded-animation/).

The problem is that my main element is set to visibility hidden, like the `load` demo [in the official documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages&view=demo:demo/index.html)

```
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

The `index.html` listens to the `WebComponentsReady` event to call a `show` function on my `library-element`:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
        document.querySelector('library-element').show(); 
    });
</script>
```

The `show` method then makes the library-element `visible` and calls the animation:

```
show: function () {
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.playAnimation('entry');
}
```

The problem that I have now is that I animate a child element that has **two** `entry` animations, that the show method wants to play. A `cascaded-animation` and a`hero-animation`.

```
animationConfig: {
    type: Object, 
    value: function () {
        return {
            'entry': [{
                name: 'cascaded-animation',
                animation: 'scale-up-animation',
            }, {
                name: 'hero-animation',
                id: 'hero',
                toPage: this
            }],
            'exit': [{
                name: 'hero-animation',
                id: 'hero',
                fromPage: this
            }, {
                name: 'fade-out-animation',
                node: this
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the `cascaded-animation` not playing, because the `hero-animation` breaks, because the `fromPage` that the `hero-animation` requires is not defined.

This is the warning I get:

> hero-animation: fromPage is undefined!

This is the error message I get:

> polymer-mini.html:2061 Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

The result is that on startup the `cascaded-animation` does not run.

---

Suggested Solutions:

**ONE:** Find a way to modify the `show` method in my `index.html` to only play the first animation. Maybe something like this:

```
show: function () {
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.playAnimation(['entry'][0]);
}
```

**TWO:** Change the `neon-shared-element-animation-behavior.html` in line 40 from this:

```
if (!fromPage || !toPage) {
    Polymer.Base._warn(this.is + ':', !fromPage ? 'fromPage' : 'toPage', 'is undefined!');
    return null;
};
```

To this:

```
if (!fromPage || !toPage) {
    console.warn(this.is + ':', !fromPage ? 'fromPage' : 'toPage', 'is undefined!');
    return null;
};
```

To what it has been before the minor patch to 1.2.2 of the `neon-animation` element. That way at least it only throws a warning, but plays the animation, instead of breaking the animation.

---

Here is the [DEMO](http://loveandhappiness.github.io/cascaded-animation/)

Click on any paper-card as often as you want, to trigger the hero and cascaded animation and observe that whenever you refresh the window the cascaded animation is not launched.

---

How do I make the `cascaded-animation` play in combination with the `hero-animation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a bug and was patched yesterday with the release of [neon-animation **1.2.3**](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/releases/tag/v1.2.3)